# Set post_parent from URL params in post-new.php

Tags: wp-insert-post

I'm trying to create a set of buttons on wordpress Page post types that allow the end user to create a new page that is a sibling (same parent page) or a child page of the current page.

In order to do so, i'm creating a link post-new.php and populating the parameter parent_id in the URL.

In my functions.php, I've hooked wp_insert_post ... the problem I have now is how to actually set the post_parent on the $post object ... I dont see any Wordpress functions to do so;  I've tried using wp_update_post ... but this doesnt seem to work for me ... here's the code in my functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_insert_post','grey_templater_set_post_parent',10,2);

function grey_templater_set_post_parent($postid,$post) {

        if ( ! $parentid = grey_get_post_parent_by_url()
                or 'auto-draft' !== $post->post_status )
                return;

        $mypage = array();
        $mypage['ID'] = $postid;
        $mypage['post_parent'] = $parentid;
        wp_update_post( $mypage );

}

function grey_get_post_parent_by_url() {

        if (! isset( $_GET['parent_id'] ) )
                return FALSE;

        return array_map('sanitize_title', explode(',', $_GET['parent_id']));
}
```

Comment: When you say update post does not work, how exaclty is it behaving? Are you sure there is a value in $postid. $postid is not a global variable, but $post is, so try `$postid = $post->ID;`

Comment: I assumed that since do_action('wp_insert_post', $post_ID, $post) passes 2 params to my hook, that the first would be the post ID.  I've done as you suggested and get the same result ... when wp_update_post is called, it seems to endlessly redirect and eventually results in an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... the problem I have now is how to actually set the post_parent on the
>   $post object ... I dont see any Wordpress functions to do so...

[From the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post):

> $post (array) (required)
>   An array representing the elements that make
>   up a post. There is a one-to-one relationship between these elements
>   and the names of columns in the wp_posts table in the database.

To set your post parent, pass `'post_parent' => <parent_id>` as part of the array that you pass to `wp_update_post`. That part should be right as far as I can tell, but as you say does not seem to work. But read on.

What you are doing creates an infinite Loop when I try it, though, since `wp_update_post` used `wp_insert_post`. You hook gets called over and over until the site runs out of memory. I suspect that that is part of the problem here. That can be fixed with this:

```
function grey_templater_set_post_parent($postid,$post) {
  remove_action('wp_insert_post','grey_templater_set_post_parent',10,2);
```

What you are also doing, potentially, is setting the post parent on a *revision*. You need to compensate.

```
$postid = (wp_is_post_revision( $postid )) ? wp_is_post_revision( $post ) : $postid;
```

But that still doesn't work. I am not sure why (I'd be happy if someone could tell me though), but I am skipping over that because this is not the hook I'd use.  Even if this worked you'd have two database writes, and you only need one. There is a hook called `wp_insert_post_data` that runs before the post is inserted/updated at all.

```
add_action('wp_insert_post_data','grey_templater_set_post_parent',10,2);

function grey_templater_set_post_parent( $data, $postarr) {
  remove_action('wp_insert_post_data','grey_templater_set_post_parent',10,2);
  if ( ! $parentid = grey_get_post_parent_by_url()
          or 'auto-draft' !== $post->post_status )
          return;
    $data['post_parent'] = $parentid; 

    return $data;
}
```

That does work, assuming your `grey_get_post_parent_by_url()` function works.

Comment: thanks ... that seems like the hook i should be looking at